# Problem to connect mysql. No suitable driver found alternating with Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

MySQL version 8.0.15
MySQL - connector - java - 8.0.15

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.sql.*;

public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Statement statement = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;


    try {
        connection =
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/firma?" +
                        "user=root&password=database123");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // handle any errors
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }

    launch(args);
}
```

I am looking for solutions and I've been struggling with it for a few hours. Reinstal was already done.
There are a few errors that appear alternately. When I do not add jara to the library, I get it:

SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/firma?user=root&password=database123
SQLState: 08001
VendorError: 0

After adding jar:

SQLException: The server time zone value 'rodkowoeuropejski czas stand' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
SQLState: 01S00
VendorError: 0

Do I modified the url to such a character because in other circumstances I had an identical error [How can i fix the problem with timezone and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608319/how-can-i-fix-the-problem-with-timezone-and-ssl)

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/firma?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC?" +
                        "user=root&password=database123");
```

and finally I receive:

SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
SQLState: 28000
VendorError: 1045

Why is not he even showing the username here?
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Database exists, user and password in url are correct.

```
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

From the console I can log in to mysql without any problem.

Please, help me. My hands are already falling...

Comment: Try changing `UTC?` to `UTC&`

Comment: Oh my God ... I am very grateful to you .. You just made me think that I should probably take a break from writing today. THANK YOU ONCE AGAIN!

Comment: No problem. Hope the rest of your project goes smoothly

Comment: I also hope. But you never know... :)